# Continuous Integration with iOS7

Tags: ios7, continuous-integration, osx-mavericks, xcode5.1, osx-server

I have an OSX Server hosted at a location different from my location. So I added the server to my Xcode 5.1, by specifying the url ioserver.myCompanyName.com . The OSX server is configured with the Git repositories hosted on some other server(I see the repositories while creating bots on web). 
Now I want to create a bot which can test and archive my code (like in CI WWDC video), but under source control when I try to check out, I don't see any repositories from the OSX server. I only see my repositories added by me under Preferences -> Accounts. Should the OSX server be present on the same server machine where my Git repositories are hosted? or there is some way to integrate a bot on every commit from my machine? Or am I doing something wrong?